# Google translator to convert text in textbox to Spanish

Tags: html, dom, google-translate

I need to get English text from one textbox and put the converted Spanish text to another text box. I cannot figure out how to achieve this:

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    includedLanguages: 'es',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE,
    autoDisplay: false
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

```html
<h1>Convert text to Spanish</h1>

<div id="google_translate_element">
  document.getElementById("title").value

</div>
<label for="Title">English Text To be converted:</label>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title">
<label for="TitleES">Convert to Spanish:</label>
<input type="text" id="titleES" name="titleES">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("title").value` is a bit of wishful thinking. You need to put that in a script tags and do something with it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/patridge/NQ4uE/